# Pass arguments from view/controller to model - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm looking to pass arguments from the controller to the model, but I keep getting wrong number of arguments.

Model:

```
before_create :embed_info

def embed_info(embed_url)
  something = embed_url
  ## Do some stuff
  self.title = "Title" ##This works.
end
```

Controller:

```
    Create action:

    @post = Post.new post_params
    @post.embed_info(params[:title])
    if @post.save
        redirect_to root_url, notice: 'post created'
    else
        render 'new'
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not pass arguments from controller to model callback like this.
You can use `attr_accessor` to create a virtual attribute and then set that attribute as part of your create action from controller.

Answer (score 0):

If you're manually invoking the `embed_info` method, you shouldn't also be invoking it automatically via a `before_create` callback. Remove the line `before_create :embed_info` as it's currently serving no purpose except to invoking `embed_info` with no arguments when you attempt to `save` your model.

It's possible that you intended to add a *validation*, which is different than a `before_create` callback. If your intent was to make sure that `embed_info` had been called then you should use validations to insure that whatever side effects `embed_info` has leave the model in a valid state.

Answer (score 0):

> but I keep getting wrong number of arguments.

You are getting an arguments error because of this: `before_create :embed_info`. You can delete that line and then explicitly call the method like you are already doing in the controller.

This is probably not best practice but I think it will get your code working.

Another thing you could do is to move the logic for deriving the `title` to the controller and then pass the title in with the params.

```
# controller
def create
  @post = Post.new post_params.merge(title: embed_info)
...

def embed_info
  something = params[:title]
  ## Do some stuff
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `attr_accessor` to create a virtual attribute of `embed_url`. Pass it in new action itself. And when you call save, before_save will be called by itself and you can use `embed_url` there (as its a virtual attribute).

Let me know if you need help if the explanation is not clear.